# Is there a simple way of checking if a column header was clicked in a TableView?

Tags: javafx, tableview

First time here. Thanks for your help.
Using java 11 with javafx for java 11.

I am using  a TableView but unable to determine if a column header was clicked  instead of one of the rows.

Having something like the line below would solve the problem as I only want  it to execute if there was a double click and the selected item is not a header.

```java
(getClickCount() == 2) && notAHeader)
```

Currently the line below will return either the first item or the last item even if the header is clicked.

```java
accountTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

If the following would return -1 when the header was clicked I could use it to solve my problem but it appears that it is only returned when nothing is selected.

```
accountTable.getSelectionModel().getFocusedIndex();
```

I tried clearing the selection at the end of the lambda.
This appears to work but it just flashes the selection on the click and is not the behavior I want.

I also tried setting a event filter to listen for the clicks and determine what I clicked contains the text of any of the headers. This solution is very ugly but it has the behavior I would like.

```java
accountTable.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (EventHandler) event -> {
                if (event.getTarget().toString().contains("Display Name") ||
                        event.getTarget().toString().contains("Username") ||
                        event.getTarget().toString().contains("Email Address")) {
                    notAHeader= false;
                } else {
                    notAHeader= true;
                }
            });
```

Code being used to configure the table.

```java
    private void configTable(TableView accountTable) {
        accountTable.setPlaceholder(new Label("Failed to load"));
        HashMap<String, String> columnHeaders = new HashMap<>();
        columnHeaders.put("Display Name", "displayName");
        columnHeaders.put("Username", "userLogonName");
        columnHeaders.put("Email Address", "emailAddress");
        columnHeaders.forEach((header, getter) -> {
                    TableColumn<String, ADAccount> column = new TableColumn<>(header);
                    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(getter));
                    accountTable.getColumns().add(column);
                }

        );
        accountTable.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                //need this to be ignored if a column header ws clicked.
                openAccountDetails(getSelectedAccount(),getMode());
            }
        });
    }
```

I  would like to be able to determine if a column header was clicked so I can ignore opening account details as the column header is not an account. Right now I am unable to distinguish between a click on the  column header and a row as the selected item does  not return any  indicators of the  column headers being selected.

Comment: what do you want to achieve, exactly?

Comment: @kleopatra  I want to know if the column header got selected.
When the header gets selected it does a  built in sort on the column but right now it also makes a selection so on my checking for the double click it also tries to openAccountDetials when the user is clicking the headers to sort.

Answer (score 0):

When the column headers is clicked the onSort is called before the sorting.
I used onSort  to clear the selection as nothing is selected when the header is clicked.

The line below gives me the behavior I needed without any side effects from what I can tell.

```
//clears the selection when the column header is selected before the sorting 
accountTable.setOnSort( e -> accountTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection());
```